# How to read csv on python with newline separator @

Tags: python, csv

I need to read a csv on Python, and the text file that I have has this structure:

```
"114555","CM13","0004","0","C/U"@"99172","CM13","0001","0","C/U"@"178672","CM13","0001","0","C/U"
```

delimeter:  ,

newline: @

My code so far:

```
import csv
data = []
with open('stock.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='@')
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'MATERIAL':  row[0],'CENTRO': row[1], 'ALMACEN': row[2], 'STOCK_VALORIZADO' : row[3], 'STOCK_UMB':row[4]})


print(data)  #this print just one row
```

This code only print one row, because it's not recognize @ as a newline,
and prints it with quotes:

```
[{'MATERIAL': '114555', 'CENTRO': 'CM13', 'ALMACEN': '0004', 'STOCK_VALORIZADO': '0', 'STOCK_UMB': 'C/U@"99172"'}]
```

Comment: [`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) "Instructs reader to perform no special processing of quote characters."  If you want it without the quotes don't use `csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

Comment: I just tried that, but still the same results. Could be a problem with the quotes?

Comment: `lineterminator` won't work.  The docs say "The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future."  This means you need to fix your data before the `csv.reader` gets to it.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Out of curiosity, who on earth writes CSVs with '@' as lineterminator?

Comment: @smci I don't know. I'm from south America and I always have to fight with the comma delimiter. but this is totally new.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html :
*"The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future."* Hence for now, providing the argument `lineterminator='@'` will not work.

I think the best option is to read your entire file into a variable, and replace all '@' characters, you can do this as follows:

```
with open("stock.csv", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace('@', '\n')
```

Now you need to adjust your algorithm in such a way that you can pass the variable `data` to `csv.reader` (instead of the file stock.csv), according to the python doc:

"*The "iterable" argument can be any object that returns a line
of input for each iteration, such as a file object or a list. [...]*"

Hence you can pass `data.splitlines()` to csv.reader.

Comment: Hopefully, none of the fields contain `'@'`, otherwise the problem gets thornier.

Comment: I agree, however I think we may asume that this is not the case here.

Comment: Might need `data.splitlines(keepends=True)`.  On normal file iteration the newlines are preserved.  The `csv.reader` may count on that. (I'm too lazy to test whether or not that's the case.)

Comment: I'm not sure about that, in the example provided by the OP, it looks like the '@' character is the actual newline character. I know this sounds weird, but without more information of the OP we cannot make any other assumptions.

Comment: What I mean is that when you iterate over a file the newlines are part of each line.  When you do `data.splitlines()` you get lines that have no line ending.  So keeping the newlines might be needed.  Otherwise your answer could be shortened to `data = myfile.read().split('@')`.  I think `data = myfile.read().replace('@', '\n').splitlines(keepends=True)` may be more correct.

Comment: Apropos @StevenRumbaski's comment, if the data is reliably structured (for example, reliably contains double-ticks to delimit column values), you can do a search for a more specific string literal that's not likely to occur. As an example, you can then easily and confidently replace `"@"`. You should be able to get even more specific if you use regular expressions and the negative lookbehind to exclude any escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with CRLF (`'\r\n'`) line endings using `csv.reader`. I was able to get it working using the `newline` parameter in `open`

```py
with open(local_file, 'r', newline='\r\n') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```