# Error while reading csv file with non standard line separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I can't read the file into memory and replace the line separator as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903366/1100089

So i wrote my own generator which yields the next row:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.encoding = 'utf-8'
    self.row_separator = '%$%$%$'
    self.column_separator = "|||"
    self.chunk_size = 2048

def get_row(self, fileObj):
    current_row = ''
    row_separator_length = len(self.row_separator)

    while True:
        # Read next chunk of data
        current_chunk = fileObj.read(self.chunk_size)
        if not current_chunk:
            # Yield last row
            if len(current_row.strip()) > 0:
                yield current_row

            break

        # Check if chunk contains row separator
        row_separator_position = current_chunk.find(self.row_separator)

        if row_separator_position == -1:
            # Chunk doesn't contain a new row => Append whole chunk
            current_row += current_chunk

            continue

        while row_separator_position > -1:
            # Chunk contains a new row => Append only until row separator
            yield current_row + current_chunk[:row_separator_position]

            # Start new row
            current_row = ''

            # Remaining characters are building a new chunk
            current_chunk = current_chunk[(row_separator_position + row_separator_length):]

            # Check if new chunk contains row separator
            row_separator_position = current_chunk.find(self.row_separator)

        # Remaining characters of chunk will be appended to next row
        current_row += current_chunk
```

The code works fine, except when the read method cuts the `row_separator` in half. So the first row would be `FOO%$%$` and the second `%$BLA`. I don't know how to proceed. Should I just check for `%` instead of `%$%$%$`, and if I find a `%`, append another chunk of data to check if `%$%$%$` was found? Or is there a simpler solution I just can't see?

**EDIT**: As suggested, here is a tangible example of the problem. As you can see, the first algorithm, mine, doesn't work, the second one (thanks @JohanL) does: https://repl.it/JoLW/3

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show at least 3 Lines of Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `.find()` rather than `.split()`? With `.split()` the row separator will be automatically removed. Together with the `iter()` function, to read the file chunks, this allows for a solution like:

```
def get_row(self, fileObj):
    buffer = ''
    row_separator_length = len(self.row_separator)
    for chunk in iter((lambda:fileObj.read(self.chunk_size)),''):
        buffer += chunk
        rows = buffer.split(self.row_separator)
        for row in rows[:-1]: # Last row might not be complete
            yield row
        buffer = rows[-1]
    rows = buffer.split(self.row_separator)
    for row in rows: # Here all rows are complete
        yield row
```

The final `rows = buffer.split(self.row_separator)` and the following `for` loop are of course needed for handling the last line of the file, when all chunks have been read.