# How to deal with a delimiter (;) at the end of each line?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with a `;` as the delimiter.
However, each line ends with a the delimiter as well. Like this:

```
A1;A2;A3;
B1;B2;B3;
C1;C2;C3;
```

Thus, my code ..

```
import csv

f = open('test.csv', 'r', newline='')
content = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
for element in content:
    print(element)
f.close()
```

.. believes that there are four values per line, with the last one being empty.

That can't be intended. Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a more elegant way to deal with this than having to delete the last value of each line?

Comment: perhaps the last `;` is meant to be a delimeter between the last item in the row and the first item in the next row. And the newline should be ignored

Comment: Why not just ignore the last field of each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar but not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903202/how-to-read-csv-on-python-with-newline-separator). There, the data is spat-out on one line with a special character used as new-line. Your problem is different as you have a file with lines but with an extra delimiter.

I couldn't find a built-in way to handle this with the `csv` module (trying to do `newline=';'` in the `open` raises an error). So similar to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903366/6045800) in the linked question, we can manipulate each line of the file before reading it as a CSV:

```py
import csv

def lines_generator(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.rstrip(';\n')

with open("test.csv", "r") as myfile:
    content = csv.DictReader(lines_generator(myfile), delimiter=';')
    for element in content:
        print(element)
```